# jquery load content in DIV, make back Button work again

Tags: jquery, html, css

iam realy new in jquery and got some problem.

I load all my different pages with .load() into one DIV.

But if i do it this way, the back Button isnt working.

How i get the back button to work?

I read some solutions here in stack but dont get them work. Can anybody help me with my code?

This is my index.html (some parts)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#mainframe").load("start.html"); 

//Geschichtebutton
$(".historyspan").click(function () { 
$('input[name=on-check]').attr('checked', false);
$('#greybox').css({'display': 'none'});
$('input[name=radio-check]').attr('checked', false);

$("#mainframe").load("geschichte.html"); 
});

//Teambutton
$(".teamspan").click(function () { 
$('input[name=on-check]').attr('checked', false);
$('#greybox').css({'display': 'none'});
$('input[name=radio-check]').attr('checked', false);

$("#mainframe").load("team.html"); 
});

//Umweltbutton
$(".umweltspan").click(function () { 
$('input[name=on-check]').attr('checked', false);
$('#greybox').css({'display': 'none'});
$('input[name=radio-check]').attr('checked', false);

$("#mainframe").load("umwelt.html");
});

});
```

Comment: This is a really flawed way of creating webpages, and navigating between them. You're waiting for the document to be ready, then you're loading the document. It's going to be be an awful user experience. Your back button won't work, as you're not actually navigating to different pages, you're loading new content into an existing page. There's nothing to go back to.

Comment: where is your back button? are u telling about browser back button?

Comment: Use `hash` and `history` plugins. Please search on Google

Comment: @ i-CONICA: So which way would you use? I dont want that the whole Page loads every time again, i dont want to use iFrame, what is opportunity three?

Comment: option 3 is building the whole thing the right way, which can be done, by implementing the history API among other things. There are plenty of websites out there that are a single page webapp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to implement your own custom urls together with the history API:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

briefly, what you would need to do, is pushing a new state in the browser history every time you `.load()` a new page. You should also update the url in the browser. In this way, the user can use the back button to navigate through the different history states.

consider that there are incosistencies across older browsers, so you might want to use history.js http://balupton.github.io/history.js/demo/ or similar